# Meager set union Bernstein set with empty interior

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, transfinite-recursion

Fix a meager set $M\subset \Bbb R$. of course  $\text{int} M=\emptyset$. I want to construct a Bernstein set $B\subset \Bbb R$ such that $$\text{int}(M\cup B)=\emptyset \tag{1}$$

We know it is true for any Bernstein set that $\text{int}B=\emptyset.$ I am not sure such $B$ can be found to make (1) true.

Any help will be appreciated greatly

Comment: Is there is a reason you stick yourself to Bernstein sets?

Comment: @HanulJeon, sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: Your questions almost always refer to Bernstein sets, and I just wonder why. (You don't need to take my question seriously.)

Comment: @HanulJeon, Bernstein set  one of the very important sets as you know and it has a lot of application. Like this question , I just thought about and I find it interesting to check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, we have a stronger result:

> Suppose $B$ is Bernstein and $M$ is meager. Then $int(M\cup B)=\emptyset$.

In the interest of brevity, I'll use an oversized hammer for the problem: the **perfect set property** for $G_\delta$ sets, that every uncountable $G_\delta$ set has a perfect subset.

Suppose $int(M\cup B)\not=\emptyset$ and $M$ is meager. Let $(a,b)\subseteq M$. Then $B\cap (a,b)$ is comeager in $(a,b)$.  We then observe:

- If $X$ is nowhere dense, then so is its closure $\overline{X}$; so every nowhere dense set is contained in a closed nowhere dense set.
- Consequently, every meager set is contained in a meager $F_\sigma$ set.
- And so dually every comeager set has a comeager $G_\delta$ subset.

And all of this relativizes to a nondegenerate open interval like $(a,b)$. So $B$ contains an uncountable $G_\delta$ set, and hence is not Bernstein by the perfect set property.

Comment: Noah Schweber,  even though I know both facts 1 and 2 but I did not know the y be useful in this question. your answer is super clear and helpful . Thank you very much

Comment: Noah Schweber    in my question i fixed meager set from the beginning. So, I want to put more stronger. There exist a Bernstein set    $B$ such that $\text{int} M\cup B$ for any meager set $M.$ probably not?

Comment: @00GB Actually, if $M$ is meager and $B$ is Bernstein we have $int(M\cup B)=\emptyset$. For suppose otherwise, and let $(a,b)\subseteq M\cup B$. Then $B\cap (a,b)$ is comeager in $(a,b)$. But every comeager set contains a comeager, hence uncountable, $G_\delta$ set, and so by the perfect set property $B$ contains a perfect set and is not Bernstein.

Comment: @00GB I've edited to include this.

Comment: Noah Schweber, This is really strong result. Thank you again

Comment: Noah, should i edit my accordingly ?

Comment: @00GB I think it's fine either way.

Comment: Noah Schwber, your pervious answer has proved in box.   Is it for the fact that says if $B$ Bernstein set and $C$ a countable set then $B\setminus C$ still Bernstein set.  If so, the way that I say it is that $B$ can be written continuum many pairwise disjoint Bernstein set so your remove countable still Bernstein set. Or it was for some thing different.

Comment: Noah Schweber, you showed in case $M\subset\Bbb R$ meager and $B\subset\Bbb R$ Bernstein set, then $\text{int}(B\cup M)=\emptyset$. But how if  $D\subset\Bbb R$ and $\text{int}(D)=\emptyset$, what we can say about $\text{int}(D\cup B)$? where $B$ as before

Comment: @00GB We can't say anything whatsoever. Having empty interior is an incredibly weak condition; for example, $int(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$. So $int(D\cup B)$ could be literally anything if all we know is that $B$ is Bernstein and $D$ has empty interior.

Comment: (And very belatedly re: your January comment, yes, removing a countable set from a Bernstein set leaves a Bernstein set: show that being Bernstein is equivalent to having uncountable intersection with every uncountable closed set, without containing any uncountable closed set. For this, note that if $P$ is uncountable and closed and $C$ is countable, then $P\setminus C$ itself contains an uncountable closed set.)

Comment: Noah Schweber. Thank you so much